# React testing library - check the existence of empty div

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a component where if `ItemLength = 1`, `render` returns `null`.

```
const { container, debug } = render(<MyComp ItemLength={1} />);
```

When I call `debug()` in my test, it shows a `<div />`. How do I check that the component is returning an empty div in my test?

Comment: `getByText(container, (content, element) => element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div')` try using getByText to match element TagName

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Update**

Use [`toBeEmptyDOMElement`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#toBeEmptyDOMElement) since `toBeEmtpy` has been deprecated.

---

You can use [jest-dom's `toBeEmpty`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobeempty):

```
const { container } = render(<MyComp ItemLength={1} />)
expect(container.firstChild).toBeEmpty()
```

Comment: It appears this toBeEmpty has been deprecated since jest-dom 5.9.0.

Comment: As @TheTFo states above, this solution appears not to work as of my writing this in late 2020.  [Karolis Grinkevičius's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267336/react-testing-library-check-the-existence-of-empty-div#57573646) works for me.

Comment: use toBeEmptyDOMElement as toBeEmpty has been deprecated

Comment: `toBeNull()` or `toBeFalsy()` is what I would use, now that toBeEmpty is deprecated

Answer (score 47):

The following should work as well without extending jest's expect:

```js
const { container } = render(<MyComp ItemLength={1} />)
expect(container.firstChild).toBeNull();
```

**Update: the new way in 2020**

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';

...

render(<MyComp ItemLength={1} />);

const child = screen.queryByTestId('data-testid-attribute-value');

expect(child).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: the new way requires you to have an ID but if ur testing something doesn't exist why would there be a test id?

Comment: @Batman it doesn't necessarily have to be `data-testid` attribute. Ideally you should be querying an element by accessibility related attributes, e.g. [screen.queryByRole](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole), [screen.queryByText](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytext) or other query documented [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/).

Comment: Yeah but what can you do if there is no role/text/anything else to query by?

Comment: @akerr In case you don't have anything specific to query for, you can always rely on using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), e.g. `document.querySelector('.yourClassName')`.

Answer (score 13):

.toHaveLength(0) should also work without jest-dom extension

```
const wrapper = render(<MyComp ItemLength={1}/>);
expect(wrapper.container.innerHTML).toHaveLength(0);
```

Answer (score 11):

`toBeEmpty` - throw warning, you must use `toBeEmptyDOMElement` instead

```js
    const pageObject = cretePage(<UserResources />, appState);

    expect(pageObject.noContent).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(pageObject.results).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
```

Answer (score 5):

To extend off the previous answers; the following works and is probably a bit cleaner with no dependence on the `data-testid` or `screen` to check for roles.

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

// Components
import { YourComponent } from "<Path>/YourComponent";

describe("YourComponent", () => {
  it("component should be an empty element", () => {
    const { container } = render(<YourComponent />);

    expect(container).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
  });

  it("component should not be an empty element", () => {
    const { container } = render(<YourComponent />);

    expect(container).not.toBeEmptyDOMElement();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use js-dom's `toBeEmptyDOMElement` method. https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobeemptydomelement

Before you can use `toBeEmptyDOMElement` you will need to install `jest-dom` and set up jest. https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#usage

```js
const { container } = render(<MyComp ItemLength={1} />)
expect(container.firstChild).toBeEmptyDOMElement()
```

Note: `toBeEmpty` method is being deprecated and its suggested to use `toBeEmptyDOMElement`

Comment: With this approach, I got `TypeError: expect(...).toBeEmptyDOMElement is not a function`

Comment: @Hiroki You need to install jest-dom before you can use it. Updating the answer to include that.`yarn add --dev @testing-library/jest-dom`

Comment: You may not have (or want) a dependency on `@testing-library/jest-dom` if you are a React Native developer. In this case, you can use `toJSON`, e.g. `expect(toJSON()).toBeNull()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to test for empty div, one way you could try to test it is by matching node (another possible solution is number of nodes rendered)

```
getByText(container, (content, element) => element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div')
```

Comment: not sure how this would work. passing `container` in throws error since it expects a `string`